# Events are not firing using WebClient ... whats wrong?

Tags: c#, events

I'm writing a utility that performs a SQL Server backup, I then compress the file and then upload it to my FTP site using WebClient. Some of the files can be quite large and I need to show the status of the upload using a ProgressBar. The WebClient offers two methods to handle this, UploadProgressChangedEventHandler and UploadFileCompletedEventHandler but WebClient is not triggering them.

I've already tried other means of copying a file using WebRequest and FtpWebRequest but they are not working properly either and WebClient seemed so simple so I went that route.

```
        try
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(txtFTPUserName.Text, txtFTPPassword.Text);
            client.UploadProgressChanged += new UploadProgressChangedEventHandler(UploadProgressChangedEventArgs);
            client.UploadFileCompleted += new UploadFileCompletedEventHandler(UploadFileCompletedEventHandler);
            progBar.Visible = true;
            progBar.Value = 0;
            client.UploadFile(@"ftp://novantconsulting.com/SQLBackups/StrataFrame.bak", @"E:\Strataframe.bak");
         }

    private void UploadProgressChangedEventArgs(object sender, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int percentage = (Convert.ToInt32(e.BytesSent) / Convert.ToInt32(e.TotalBytesToSend)) * 100;

        if (progBar.Value < progBar.Maximum)
        {
            progBar.Value = percentage;
        }
        else
        {
            progBar.Value = 100;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that WebClient is not raising the events so that the delegate can do its job of updating the ProgressBar.  I've been told that this is a known problem with WPF but I'm using WinForms so that problem does not apply

Comment: Please fix your example code. You got a try block without catch or finally - and outside of any function. If this is your real code, there is no way this compiles.

Comment: I didn't post the full try catch finally block as it didn't seem to be germane to the question. The instructions during the post told to post the bare minimum to get the idea of the question across.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [`WebClient.UploadProgressChanged` Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadprogresschanged#remarks), the event is only raised for uploads initiated by calling the [`UploadDataAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploaddataasync), [`UploadFileAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadfileasync), or [`UploadValuesAsync` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadvaluesasync).

According to [`WebClient.UploadFileCompleted` Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadfilecompleted#remarks), the event is only raised for uploads initiated by calling the [`UploadFileAsync` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadfileasync).

In short, the [`UploadFile` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadfile) you are calling does not raise those events; use [`UploadFileAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadfileasync) instead.